# Accessing the DI container from anywhere

Tags: zend-framework, dependency-injection

I've implemented the Symfony2 Dependency Injection container in my Zend Framework project and it works fine in the MVC layer of my application. I've initialized the DIC in my bootstrap and  can access it anywhere by calling:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getDic()
```

The problem is that there are some parts of my application that do not utilize the Zend Framework application/MVC layer. My CLI tools for example. I could perfectly initialize a new DIC there but that would just be some copy paste work from the Bootstrap file which is asking for trouble down the road (DRY principles, etc)

Is it a better solution to make my DIC available in the `Zend_Registry` or as a singleton called by a static method `DIC::getInstance()` for example?

I know Registry and singletons are considered bad things but the DIC is such a high level part of the application that I will probably never run into the problems that make it a bad thing.

Is this a good solution or are there better ways of accomplishing a globally accessible DIC?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this in the past using [**Pimple**](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) (created by Fabien Potencier, owner of Symfony).

> Pimple is a small Dependency Injection Container for PHP 5.3 that consists of just one file and one class (about 50 lines of code).

Here is how I coupled it with my ZF1 application:

1. Create a new Pimple container into your application's bootstrap
2. Declare all your services with proper dependencies
3. Access the DIC through your controllers or CLI tools
4. Access the services through the DIC

If your services are well declared (injecting dependencies through their constructors) you shouldn't have to access the DIC outside your controllers or CLI tools.

Use a base controller class to easily access the DIC through `$this->container`:

```
abstract class MyApp_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    protected $container;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->container = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
                               ->getParam('bootstrap')->getDic();
    }
}
```

---

In order to use your DIC into your CLI tools:

1. Extend `Zend_Application` to create your CLI application
2. Override `run()` to prevent the MVC stack to bootstrap
3. When creating your CLI tool inject the DIC through its constructor

Use a base command class to easily access the DIC through `$this->container`:

```
abstract class MyApp_Command
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand what i'm asking, I'm having no problems accessing my DIC in the MVC stack or any classes using it. I've done the same as you did with pimple but instead with the Symfony2 container. Problem is that when i'm not using the MVC stack the bootstrap isn't used (CLI tools for example) thus the DIC is not initialized, this makes me wonder if the Bootstrap is actually the right place to initialize it in my case.

Comment: Why don't you initialize your bootstrap with your CLI tools? Create an application class which extends `Zend_Application` and override `run()` to disable `Zend_Front_Controller` bootstrapping. Then you will able to use your bootstrapped resources without the MVC stack.

Comment: Yes but then accessing the DIC isn't possible with `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()` since I haven't got a FrontController. That's why I'm asking if there is a better option to access the DIC (registry, singleton, ...) in the CLI part of my app and perhaps also in my MVC stack.

Comment: Since you are not using the MVC stack you could inject your DIC through your CLI tools' constructors.

Comment: True, but that still doesn't solve the issue that accessing the DIC is totally different in my MVC stack and my CLI tools. When I want to use a library in my CLI tools that i'm also using in my MVC stack i've got two different ways to access the DIC. I want accessing the DIC to be the same, wether i'm in the MVC stack or in the DIC.

Comment: Added some code to show you how you can access the DIC using the same code (through `$this->container`).

Comment: I see, injecting the container through the constructor, but what if i'm using a class that's used both in the MVC layer and in the CLI tools? In the MVC layer i'm accessing it through the Front_Controller and in the CLI tools i'm accessing it through constructor injection. That makes 2 different ways to access the DI in one class.

Comment: I think that having a base class for controllers and CLI tools is a bad idea since controllers need to extend `Zend_Controller_Action` and CLI tools don't.

Answer (score 1):

To have access to your bootstrap ressources in your CLI file you can go and do a partial bootstrapping of your application

Instead of doing this (public/index.php) and bootstraping your whole application :

```
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

You can do this and only bootstrap the required resouces :

```
$app = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH .  '/configs/application.ini'
);

// Selectively bootstrap resources:
$app->bootstrap('db');
$app->bootstrap('log');
$app->bootstrap('autoload');
$app->bootstrap('config');
$app->bootstrap('di');
```

You have to make sure that you initialize them in the right order (you might need to have your DB loaded before the logging component if you have a DB writter for your logs for example).

From there, you can call parts of your bootstrap (for the DI component, you can call the `$app->getBootstrap()->getContainer()`. You have access to all methods available in your bootstrap.